# Expected value of a summation of random variable when $N$ is also a RV

Tags: summation, random-variables, conditional-expectation, expected-value, variance

What would be the expected value of $S$ and its variance given $S$ such as a follow:

$$ S = \sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i, $$

and here $X_i$ and $N$ are both random variable.

Comment: Use the linearity of expectation, or the law of iterated expectation.

Comment: Without the assumption on the joint distribution (such as independence between $N$ and $X_i$'s), nothing specific can be said.

Comment: See [Wald's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%27s_equation).

Comment: Assuming the $X_i$ are i.i.d. and $N$ is a nonnegative integer-valued random variable independent of the $X_i$, then $$\mathbb E\left[\sum_{i=1}^N X_i\right] = \mathbb E[X_1]\mathbb E[N]. $$
There are more general conditions under which this equality holds, however.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $X$ and $N$ are independent, let $S_N=\sum_{i=1}^NX_i$, then $E(S_N|N=n)=\sum_{i=1}^nE(X_i)$  Let $P_n=prob(N=n)$, then $E(S)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty P_n\sum_{i=1}^nE(X_i)$